# Replace text in the Title

Tags: title, get-the-title, customization, wp-title

In a string displayed by `<?php the_title(); ?>` I have to replace all `&` characters with `and`.

Here is the code I've tried without success:

```
<?php $wptitle = the_title(); $wptitle = str_replace('&', 'and', $wptitle);?><?php echo $wptitle; ?>
```

The full code to be replaced:

```
<h2><a href="<?php if(get_post_meta($post->ID, 'links_link_custom', true)): ?><?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'links_link_custom', true) ?><?php else: ?><?php the_permalink(); ?><?php endif; ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
```

Comment: Please properly format your code, it is really hard keeping count because everything is sqeezed into one single loooooonnnnngggg line :-)

Answer (score 4):

First things first, lets clean up your code:

```
<?php $wptitle = the_title(); $wptitle = str_replace('&', 'and', $wptitle);?><?php echo $wptitle; ?>
```

Lets remove the PHP tag spam and put things in nice clean lines:

```
<?php
$wptitle = the_title();
$wptitle = str_replace('&', 'and', $wptitle);
echo $wptitle;
?>
```

Now if we look at the problem, `the_title`, that function outputs the title and doesn't return anything. This means `$wptitle` is empty, so your string replace does nothing.

You need to tell it to return it or it won't know, computers aren't the same as people, they need to be told explicitly what to do with no assumptions.

However, a quick google for `the_title` [brings up the codex as the first entry](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_title), along with [a related function](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_title/) `get_the_title` which would solve your problem. Reading the documentation says that these are the arguments this function takes:

```
<?php the_title( $before, $after, $echo ); ?>
```

So you can change `$wptitle = the_title();` to this:

```
$wptitle = the_title( '','',false );
```

Or this:

```
$wptitle = get_the_title();
```

There is also a much better method that you can use involving filters:

```
add_filter( 'the_title', 'drabello_swap_ampersands' );
function drabello_swap_ampersands( $old_title ) {
    $new_title = // do the replacement..
    return $new_title;
}
```

Comment: I am using the filter but it's displaying "and" followed by a hashtag and numbers (seems html) like this "and#8211;". here is the filter: `add_filter( 'the_title', 'drabello_swap_ampersands' );
function drabello_swap_ampersands( $old_title ) {
    $new_title = str_replace('&', 'and', $old_title);
    return $new_title;
}`

Comment: I did some tests, the filter is not working only when this **"&"** symbol is used. But this is exactly what I have to change. @TomJNowell Do you know why?

Comment: Are you sure that's an ampersand? and not a special unicode character? Your sentence doesn't really make sense. The ampersand removal code works when there is no ampersand to remove, but doesn't when there's an ampersand?

Comment: Sorry but I am lost now. I want to replace the ampersand with the word "and". With you filter I am able to replace any other word, i.e. **replace('Ball', 'and', $old_title)**. But when I try **replace('&', 'and', $old_title)** I get encode errors in the title. @TomJNowell

Comment: Where are you checking this? This filter won't change the post title on the post edit screen, it only changes the title when it's being displayed. Dealing with HTML encoding errors is a separate issue that can be solved purely with PHP and string manipulation, that's not a WordPress issue